# NOOB selenium rspec test not passing

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, selenium-rc

I have the following integration test. It loads a page with a form on it. The submit button is pressed without any data so the form should show an error box. The form is submitted with ajax and should put the form back on the page with the errors.

I can see this in the browser but the test fails.

What am I doing wrong? I am a complete NOOB so need some guidance.

require 'spec_helper'
    require "rubygems"

```
describe "Boards" do

  describe "board creation failure" do
    attr_reader :selenium_driver
    alias :page :selenium_driver

    before(:all) do
      @verification_errors = []
      @selenium_driver = Selenium::Client::Driver.new \
        :host => "localhost",
        :port => 4444,
        :browser => "*chrome",
        :url => "http://localhost:3000/",
        :timeout_in_second => 60
    end

    before(:each) do
      @selenium_driver.start_new_browser_session
    end

    after(:each) do
      @selenium_driver.close_current_browser_session
      @verification_errors.should == []
    end

    it "should show the error explanation div" do
      page.open "/"
      page.click "board_submit"
      page.is_element_present("error_explanation").should be_true #should show error box
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.

I needed to add the following metho to tell Selenium to wait until all of the ajax calls were completed.

I put this method in my spec/spec_helper.rb file and made sure to have require 'spec_helper' in the file.

Here is the method in spec_helper.rb:

```
      #needed for selenium ajax testing
      def wait_for_ajax(timeout=5000)
          js_condition = 'selenium.browserbot.getUserWindow().jQuery.active == 0'
          @selenium_driver.wait_for_condition(js_condition, timeout)
      end



    #needed for selenium ajax testing

  def selenium_setup

      @verification_errors = []
      @selenium_driver = Selenium::Client::Driver.new \
      :host => "localhost",
      :port => 4444,
      :browser => "*firefox",
      :url => "http://localhost:3000/",
      :timeout_in_second => 60
      #return @selenium_driver
  end
```

As you can see above I also moved the setup code for the selenium_driver to the spec_helper.rb file to clean up my code and make it more DRY:

Here are my integration tests file:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Board  form" do
  attr_reader :selenium_driver
  alias :page :selenium_driver

  before(:all) do
    selenium_setup
    @selenium_driver.start_new_browser_session
  end

  after(:all) do
    @selenium_driver.close_current_browser_session
    @verification_errors.should == []
  end

    describe "create board" do
      describe "failure" do
        it "test_ home page form" do
            page.open "/"
            ("Happy Birthday Greetings | Home").should == page.get_title
            page.is_element_present("board_bp_name").should be_true
            page.is_text_present("Name").should be_true
            ("Happy Birthday Greetings | Home").should == page.get_title
            page.click "board_submit"
            wait_for_ajax
            page.is_element_present("board_bp_name").should be_true
            page.is_text_present("Name").should be_true
            page.is_element_present("board_birthday_1i").should be_true
            page.is_element_present("board_submit").should be_true
            page.is_text_present("exact:Oops, looks like 1 error occured: \n Hey whose birthday is it? Please enter a name.").should be_true
            page.is_element_present("error_explanation").should be_true
        end
      end

      describe "success" do

        it "should create a new board for a properly filled in form and show the correct flash message" do
            page.open "/"
            page.type "board_bp_name", "Test User"
            page.select "board_birthday_2i", "label=October"
            page.select "board_birthday_1i", "label=1967"
            page.select "board_birthday_3i", "label=7"
            page.click "board_submit"
            wait_for_ajax
            page.wait_for_page_to_load("30000")
            page.get_location().should =~ /boards\/\d/i
            page.is_element_present("css=div.flash.success").should be_true
            page.is_text_present("Your friend's board has been created.").should be_true
            page.is_text_present("Test User").should be_true
            page.is_text_present("43").should be_true
            page.is_element_present("greeting_link").should be_true
            page.is_text_present("Add greeting").should be_true
        end
      end
    end
  end
```